# SparkR Write into a Parquet file

Tags: parquet, sparkr

I am trying to write a data frame into a parquet format. The data frame is

> str(test)
>   'data.frame':   365 obs. of  4 variables:
>    $ id      : chr  "Apple" "Apple" "Apple" "Apple" ...
>    $ text    : chr  "譲渡 拡散希望\npsychopass サイコパス　トレーディングラバーストラップ 宜野座伸元\n特典円通常円送料にてお譲りします検索からでもお"| **truncated** "retweet\n\npeachpanther albumin the world right now" "haarlem vacature internet strateeg opzoek naar cto software architectlead developer star applehaarl" "ในอายทเทากน\nผหญงมความเปนผใหญมากกวาผชาย\nไมมผชายคนไหนไปไดสวยกบผหญงอายเทากนไดหรอก\n you are the a""| **truncated** ...
>    $ emotion : chr  "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" ...
>    $ polarity: chr  "positive" "positive" "positive" "positive" ...

When i try to use write.parquet i get the following error

write.parquet(test,"hdfs://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9000/orcladv/intdata/processedtweets")
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘write.parquet’ for signature ‘"data.frame", "character"’

Has anyone faced this issue. Please help me solve this.

Regards

Bala

Answer (score 1):

"data.frame" in the error message indicates you are using an R data.frame.  The write.parquet() function you are using operates on Spark DataFrames not R data.frames.

Details of how to convert between the two here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html#creating-dataframes

Comment: Thanks. I tried to do what is suggested, however i am hitting another error now.

16/06/27 11:25:14 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 8.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
16/06/27 11:25:14 ERROR RBackendHandler: dfToCols on org.apache.spark.sql.api.r.SQLUtils failed
Error in invokeJava(isStatic = TRUE, className, methodName, ...) :
  org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 8.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 8.0 (TID 440, sghdp0): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "Rscript": error=2, No such file or director

Comment: Thanks again for that SpiritusPrana. I sorted the next problem that i stated. That was because  my Rscript was not in the path. Once i got that into my $PATH write.parquet works. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Glad I could help @BalajiKrishnan.  If the answer helped, grateful if you could accept the answer.